# error in facebook logout

Tags: android, facebook, logout

Im using the below code to logout from the fb in my application. this code gives an error to the logout, I can't figure out the issue , any help will be appreciated.

error message is

The method logout(Context, AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener) in the type AsyncFacebookRunner is not applicable for the arguments (ProfileFragment, new AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener(){})

```
 final RelativeLayout relativeLayout3 = (RelativeLayout) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.logoutlistview);
        relativeLayout3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                logoutFromFacebook();
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    public void logoutFromFacebook() {
        AsyncFacebookRunner asyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
        asyncRunner.logout(getActivity(), new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
                if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                             LandingActivity.class);
                             startActivity(intent);
                             intent.addFlags(IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                             | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                             startActivity(intent);
                             getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,
                             R.anim.slide_out_left);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }
```

output in my logcat

[image]

if there is a better way to logout from the system please suggest it,

Comment: where you run this code in Fragment or in Activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in `Fragment`

```
  asyncRunner.logout(getActivity(), new RequestListener() {
```

You should pass **context** as first argument in `asyncRunner.logout(....)`

Comment: @JohnDavid do as per my answer. `getActivity()` used to get context in `Fragment`

Comment: hey can u check my updated question because when I presslogout it shows that output in my logcat. Im bit confused there, can u help me to understand what is that

Comment: @JohnDavid do as per my answer and your logcat is not related to your problem.

Comment: i changed it and it removed the error. now when i run the application im getting this output in my logcat. im confused what is that output

Comment: ok thnx.. i saw someone has posted the question but no proper answer for that

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
public static void facebookLogout(Context context) {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null) {

            if (!session.isClosed()) {
                session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            }
        } else {

            session = new Session(context);
            Session.setActiveSession(session);

            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        }

    }
```

Comment: can i use this code inside fragment? it gives error to context

Comment: Yes you can just call this function like: `facebookLogout(getActivity()); `

Comment: im getting an error in my logcat, can u please check my updated question screenshot

Comment: You have not set your App Id in the strings.xml file: `<string name="app_id">2483970XXXXXXXX</string>` Please copy the App Id from your faceboox Console for this particular App and paste that with this tag in the strings.xml file.

Comment: now i added to manifest.xml file as well, but still getting the error

Comment: 157th line, if (session != null) {

Comment: if ( !facebook.isSessionValid()) {
Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
ActivityMenu.class);
startActivity(i);,  this is how my condtion check wether i hav logged in thru fb, is there any issue with that.?